# SQL Query Optimization (Mysql 5.7)

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have following query to execute in live mysql 5.7, which takes around 7 sec and we want to reduce their time, please share your thoughts

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(
          DISTINCT InternalInquiry.inquiry_id
     ) AS "count" 
FROM
     internal_inquiries `InternalInquiry` 
     LEFT JOIN cpml_projects `Project` 
          ON (
               Project.project_id = InternalInquiry.object_id 
               AND Project.agent_id = 159297
          ) 
     INNER JOIN clients `Client` 
          ON (
               Client.clientid = InternalInquiry.clientID
          ) 
     INNER JOIN 
          (SELECT DISTINCT 
               (InternalInquiry.inquiry_id) AS "id" 
          FROM
               internal_inquiries `InternalInquiry` 
                LEFT JOIN internal_inquiries_sharing `InternalInquirySharing` 
                    ON (
                         InternalInquiry.inquiry_id = InternalInquirySharing.inquiry_id 
                    )
          WHERE (
                    (
                      InternalInquiry.userid IN ( 399724, 420710, 438389, 535916, 535917, 541643, 541644)
                       OR InternalInquirySharing.share_with IN ( 399724, 420710, 438389, 535916, 535917, 541643, 541644)
                     ) 
               ) 
               AND  (
                    InternalInquiry.status IN (
                         1, 21, 26, 14, 4, 15, 13, 5, 16, 17, 18, 22, 25, 2, 10, 3, 19, 20, 23, 11, 12, 24, 9, 8, 28
                    )
               ) 
               AND (
                    InternalInquiry.time_added >= '2013-11-01 00:00:00' 
                    AND InternalInquiry.time_added <= '2018-11-22 23:59:59'
               )) dd 
          ON dd.id = InternalInquiry.inquiry_id 
WHERE (
          InternalInquiry.firmstate != 'deleted'
     ) 
     AND (
          InternalInquiry.status IN (
               1, 21, 26, 14, 4, 15, 13, 5, 16, 17, 18, 22, 25, 2, 10, 3, 19, 20, 23, 11, 12, 24, 9, 8, 28
          )
     ) 
     AND (
          InternalInquiry.time_added >= '2013-11-01 00:00:00' 
          AND InternalInquiry.time_added <= '2018-11-22 23:59:59'
     ) 
     AND (
           Client.client_status != 1 AND
           Client.client_agency = 159297
     )
```

Execution plan as follow:

```
 id  select_type  table                   partitions  type    possible_keys                                                                                                         key                               key_len  ref                                       rows  filtered  Extra                         
------  -----------  ----------------------  ----------  ------  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  --------------------------------  -------  --------------------------------------  ------  --------  ------------------------------
     1  PRIMARY      <derived2>              (NULL)      ALL     (NULL)                                                                                                                (NULL)                            (NULL)   (NULL)                                  143661    100.00  (NULL)                        
     1  PRIMARY      InternalInquiry         (NULL)      eq_ref  PRIMARY,clientID,time_added,firmstate,search_inquiry_basic_index                                                      PRIMARY                           4        dd.id                                        1     12.50  Using where                   
     1  PRIMARY      Client                  (NULL)      eq_ref  PRIMARY,client_agency,client_status,com_1                                                                             PRIMARY                           4        InternalInquiry.clientID                     1     25.00  Using where                   
     1  PRIMARY      Project                 (NULL)      ref     project_id                                                                                                            project_id                        5        InternalInquiry.object_id                    1    100.00  Using where                   
     2  DERIVED      InternalInquiry         (NULL)      ALL     PRIMARY,clientID,userid,object_type,next_status_wanted,time_added,firmstate,search_inquiry_basic_index,idx_object_id  (NULL)                            (NULL)   (NULL)                                  544996     25.00  Using where; Using temporary  
     2  DERIVED      InternalInquirySharing  (NULL)      ref     internal_inquiries_sharing_UN,inquiry_id                                                                               internal_inquiries_sharing_UN    5        InternalInquiry.inquiry_id                   1    100.00  Using where; Using index
```

I am sharing indexes information for main table

[image: internal_inquiries]

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to help you. We need to know your table and index definitions. Please read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Then please [edit] your question. Also, you're more likely to get answers if you can show us a simpler query with the same performance issue: that one is big.

Comment: I added information for main table

Comment: dup of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/223424/sql-query-optimization-mysql-5-7

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Please do not encourage people to crosspost: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you don't have an index covering main criteria in both inner and outer query on the main table. There may be some more fine-tuning, but this should be a good start:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_internal_inquiries_status_timeadded
    ON internal_inquiries
    (status, time_added);
```

Also, versions with `inquiry_id` and/or `firmstate` could be of value, but it must be tested:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_internal_inquiries_inquiryid_status_timeadded, firmstate
    ON internal_inquiries
    (inquiry_id, status, time_added, firmstate);
```

Just try a few combinations and see if it gets you any further.

Answer (score 0):

To start, you are only getting a count, but never utilizing an INNER JOIN on the projects table, so you dont need that. I would remove it.  Your inner query and outer query are BOTH pulling the same criteria on status, date/time. So I would remove that from the inner and just keep your user_id/ShareWith criteria.  I then moved the client WHERE criteria to that instance's JOIN clause.

Simplified the date to just the date 2013-11-01 since with no time is implied as 00:00:00.  Also change the ending time to LESS THAN 2018-11-23 which implies inclusive of 2018-11-22 up to 11:59:59pm.

Finally, your inner query to the shared context.  We know it is a must-join via INNER, and appears you only care about specific users in the inquiry OR shared.  So I slightly altered to left-join on the sharing, but only for the OTHER SHARE WITH user and shifted to the where clause

```
SELECT 
      COUNT( DISTINCT II.inquiry_id ) AS "count" 
   FROM
      internal_inquiries II 
         INNER JOIN clients `Client` 
            ON II.clientID = C.clientid
           AND C.client_agency = 159297
           AND C.client_status != 1 
         LEFT JOIN internal_inquiries_sharing IIS
            ON II.inquiry_id = SharedUser.inquiry_id 
            AND IIS.share_with IN ( 399724, 420710, 438389, 535916, 535917, 541643, 541644 )
   WHERE 
          II.firmstate != 'deleted'
      AND II.status IN ( 1, 21, 26, 14, 4, 15, 13, 5, 16, 17, 18, 22, 25, 2, 10, 3, 19, 20, 23, 11, 12, 24, 9, 8, 28 )
      AND II.time_added >= '2013-11-01' 
      AND II.time_added < '2018-11-23'
      AND ( II.userid IN ( 399724, 420710, 438389, 535916, 535917, 541643, 541644)
            OR IIS.Inquery_ID IS NOT NULL )
```

In addition, I would ensure the following indexes exist on the respective tables

```
table                       index
Internal_Inquiries          ( time_added, status, user_id, firmstate, inquiry_id )
Client                      ( clientID, Client_Agency, client_status )
internal_inquiries_sharing  ( share_with, inquiry_id )
```

Since the outer query is pre-restricting based on the status and time, we know we are getting ALL possible users and don't need to add that extra criteria to the join for shares.  The LAST part of the WHERE clause will apply for the single user OR the user found as a share.

One last possible addition to the query would be to add the STRAIGHT_JOIN keyword specific to MySQL via

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN  Count( distinct ….
```